# How to write a bc calculated variable to file using CRON jobs (linux, bash, script, cron)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I am a lot confused about this behavior.
Each time I run this script from terminal, it works fine, but it fails once is executed from a crontab.
Inside the script you can find each step description.
The target is to print date and time with the **peso** variable to a file.
I have changed line 16 countless times. Same thing for line #4.

Edit for clarity: THIS IS JUST A SMALL PART FROM THE WHOLE SCRIPT.
It runs nice every minute. It does everything, except the **peso** issue.

Please HELP!!!

```
1 # Here I compute one decimal value (like z=0.123) with two integers (sd and mean)
2 peso=$( echo "scale=4; ${z}*${sd}/100 + ${mean}/100" | bc -l) 
3 echo "peso_mtrx="$peso       # This is for checking: shows 40.123 (example), so it is OK
4 peso+=";"                    # Add a semicolon to check its behaviour
5 echo "peso= "$peso           # show it: OK
6 peso1=$(date "+%D %T")       # Now I capture date and time
7 echo "fecha= "$peso1         # shows it, so it is OK
8 peso1+=";"                   # add a semicolon to date
9 peso1+=$peso                 # concatenate the peso variable
10 echo $(printf '%s' "$peso1") # shows it, so it is ok up to here

11 echo $(printf '%s' "$peso1") >> ~/projects/Files/normal.csv           # WRITE TO FILE

12 # whenever I run this script from terminal, all variables showed right and even print all data into file.
13 # File stores a new line like:  02/03/21 08:24:40;40.1709; 

14 # BUT... when it is executed from a CRON job... everything except peso are stored.
15 # File stores a line like:  02/03/21 08:24:40;; peso variable just vanishes.

16 # is it something related to subshells? how to solve this rigmarole?
```

Comment: Try redirecting the output to a file to see what is going on when it is being executed with cron

Comment: If you want bash to run this, the first line should be `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Raman, Thank you for your interest. What is written in lines 12 through 15 shows what happened when I write to file. This is done in the line 11.  ACTUAL OUTPUTS IN FILE FROM RUNNING FROM TERMINAL: 02/04/21 08:44:20;40.1370;  
AND RUNNING FROM CRON: 02/04/21 08:45:02;;

Comment: Hi Roadwol... this is just a part from the whole script. Which in fact runs nice except for the peso variable.

Comment: What about the rest of the output in cron logs? Do they have a value for `$peso`? Where and how do you set `$z`, `$sd`, `$mean`? What happens if you directly set `peso` to a string instead of the `bc` command substitution?

Comment: Thank you Benjamin:
$z has 0.123 (it comes from a random process)
$sd is a value like 15 (integer)
$mean is like 4015 (integer)
$peso is the calculated value ($z*$sd + $mean)/100 : it is something like 40.1684.

As far as I know, bc does the floating point calculation.

Comment: What Roadowl mentions is pertinent and whether your code is part of a larger script doesn't make it irrelevant : if your script doesn't have the `#!/bin/bash` shebang it will be run by `cron` in posix-compliant mode (with an `sh` interpreter rather than `bash`) by default and a lot of your script wouldn't work as intended, which could explain the different output

Comment: Thank You Aaron. Script has it.  
#!/bin/bash  
while true; do  
    base1=10  
    base2=10  
    base3=10  
    base4=10  
    base5=10  
    base6=10  
    base7=10  
    aleat1=$RANDOM...

Answer (score 1):

As I was suspicious, the whole thing was related to subshell issues.
I just did something inside ***crontab***.
Once I execute `crontab -e`, I initially had something like:

```
*/1 * * * * /absolute/path/to/project.sh
```

So doing some reading I ended up doing this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
*/1 * * * * exec bash -l /absolute/path/to/project.sh
```

I beg to an expert to enlighten us about this solution. As far as I do understand, it is related to create a login shell inside cron using the information stored in `.bash_profile`.
It did enable the environment variables to be reachable.